# Background location updates sometimes fail in iOS 11

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location

I'm currently working on an iOS app which is fetching the location on background. My simulator's iOS version is 11.1. I don't know whether someone else facing this problem?

I'm initializing my CLLocationManager on my first ViewController and terminating the app after the initialization.

If i press the home button and go to homescreen (which makes my app    to work on background, the location has sent to my Node Server    properly, but whenever i terminate app manually from the multitasking    screen. The location fetching is stopping even i set the location    mode as **Freeway Drive** from simulator's settings.)

I have also added the plist privacy description also. Below the
   picture.

[image: My info.plist has set as this]

Here is my code,

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  BackgroundDeneme
//
//  Created by Alican Yilmaz on 01/11/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 Alican Yilmaz. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var manager:CLLocationManager!

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.manager = CLLocationManager()
        self.manager.delegate = self
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()



    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations.first
        let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01,longitudeDelta: 0.01)
        let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((location?.coordinate.latitude)!, (location?.coordinate.longitude)!)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: myLocation, span: span)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        let longitude = String(describing: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let latitude = String(describing: location!.coordinate.latitude)
        let speed = String(describing: location!.speed)
        let accuracy = String(describing: " buviewdengelme \(String(describing: location!.verticalAccuracy)) \(location!.horizontalAccuracy)")
        UpdateLocation.entryLocation(longitude: longitude,latitude: latitude,speed: speed,accuracy: accuracy)                
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("location Almada problem var: \(error)" )
    }
}



class UpdateLocation{
    static func entryLocation(longitude:String, latitude:String, speed:String, accuracy:String){
        let todoEndpoint: String = "http://172.27.108.114:4000/location"
        guard let url = NSURL(string: todoEndpoint) else {
            return
        }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "longitude=\(longitude)&latitude=\(latitude)&speed=\(speed)&accuracy=\(accuracy)"
        urlRequest.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
            if (error != nil) {
                print("ERROR VAR: \(error)")
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: That's expected. When you force quit the app, your location services are killed—unless you have geofence or SignificantLocationChanges (SLC) enabled.

Comment: But, this code works occasionally. Yesterday i've uploaded this code into my iOS 11 real device, the (standard, not SLC)location updates was OK in the background even the app is terminated manually.

So how this would be happened. Am i missing something?

Comment: `MKCoordinateRegion` is geofence. Which can launch the app again even after termination.

Comment: you've resolved by my suggestions or it was because of something else?

Comment: i realized that, when i force kill the app, location services killed. But when it was publishing locations, it was because of the standardLocation after the app waked up by iOS by significantLocationMonitoring.